# Using Raster Tracer in QGIS v3.6.1 and it's not working

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, vector, digitizing

I've been trying to use raster tracer to trace some lines on simple rasters in QGIS v3.6.1, but when I use the plugin it returns the following error:

2020-06-22T11:48:25     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\raster_tracer\pointtool.py", line 217, in canvasReleaseEvent
i1, j1 = self.to_indexes(x1, y1)
AttributeError: 'PointTool' object has no attribute 'to_indexes'

Does anybody know how I can rectify this to make the plugin work or can anyone provide more information about the plugin, as there is very little information on it?

Comment: doesnt look like the plugin has had any development since last december. could be a  version issue, try on a different installation. Could be related to the vector  layer that you are using, ensure  everything is  projected properly, use a temporary blank layer.

Comment: Can you give more information so it would be possible reprocude the error?